# Autocomplete for domain users

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there any way to do autocomplete for domain users in .net?
Meaning, I want a textbox that when I will start and type Admin, it will complete it to \Administrator

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a web application? Winforms? WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can hold a list of all valid domain account names and use an [autocomplete](http://www.vbnettutorial.net/?Id=135&Desc=VB.net-ComboBox-AutoComplete) (winforms example) with that data source.

Of course, this means you are exposing some sensitive information.

Comment: Usernames aren't secret: http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2011/10/17/1801349.aspx

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this for displaying domain user names ......

```
namespace AutoCompleteTextBox
{
  public partial class frmAuto : Form
  {
     public string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"];
     AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection  =  new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
     public frmAuto()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void frmAuto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
              SqlDataReader dReader;
               SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
               conn.ConnectionString = strConnection;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                 cmd.CommandText ="Select distinct [Name] from [Names]" + " order by [Name] asc";
                  conn.Open();
               dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              if (dReader.HasRows == true)
              {
                     while (dReader.Read())
                     namesCollection.Add(dReader["Name"].ToString());

               }
               else
               {
                        MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
                }
                dReader.Close();

                txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;

         }
         private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                  Application.Exit();
          }
          private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
                MessageBox.Show(" this is autocomplete text box  example");
           }

       }
}
```